# How to add interpolated item to array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation, h5py

If I have a one dimensional (column) that has 999 item (numbers only), how can I put an interpolated number between the item 500 and 501?

```
a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Ad/Desktop//H5 Files/3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])
output = np.column_stack((a.flatten(order="C"))
np.savetxt('merged.csv',output,delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Here the recommended way to read an array from the H5 dataset: `a=h5py.File('/Users/Ad/Desktop//H5 Files/3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'][()]` Also, it would be better to use Python's `with/as` context manager to access the file.
`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not clear, but try

```
numpy.insert(array, 501, value)
```

Note that the second argument is the index **before** which the new element will be inserted.

More:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Answer (score 0):

With such a short array, you could just add the value to the end and sort!
Still, you can find the index and insert it!

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Beware, you may need to change the type of your array to insert a non-integer value

```py
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> np.insert(arr, 5, 4.4) 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.insert(arr.astype("float64"), 5, 4.4) 
array([0. , 1. , 2. , 3. , 4. , 4.4, 5. , 6. , 7. , 8. , 9. ])
```